# Overhead of glDrawArrays vs. glMultiDrawArrays

Tags: opengl

Can someone tell what exactly causes the overhead of a loop of multiple glDrawArrays calls without state changes over one glMultiDrawArrays call? Like, why this

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_objects; i++) {
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,
                 object[n]->first_vertex,
                 object[n]->vertex_count);
}
```

is supposedly more expensive than one glMultiDrawArrays call?

Answer (score 4):

You probably came to believe this due to reading somewhere about "reducing draw calls" or something of the sort. And that's true: fewer draw calls is better than more draw calls from a performance standpoint.

However, when it comes to OpenGL, it isn't really "draw calls" that are the problem. It is the *state changes* that you do between draw calls that make a draw call slow. If you don't actually change any state from one draw to the next, then they're actually quite fast.

Now, sequential draws will probably not be quite as fast as a multidraw. But that's because, every time you issue a draw call, the implementation has to ask the question, "Did the user change any rendering state?" Now, a good implementation will probably set a bit somewhere in every state changing function, so that this check boils down to just checking a boolean value. But it still has to be done for each draw. A multidraw only does that check once.

But that's generally a trivial performance difference.

Comment: This is why my question basically comes down to "is there anything beside state change checks that makes a draw call expensive"?

Comment: I can "imagine" a lot of things; that doesn't make them true. If the start index required "a major state change", why would that not be the case for each internal draw in a multi-draw command? And how could *indirect* multidraw functions ever possibly work, since the whole point of them is that the GPU directly reads the drawing parameters from GPU memory? How could it induce such a state change?

Comment: I withdrew that comment and would like to go back to the first follow-up: "is there anything beside state change checks that makes a draw call expensive"?